# Optimizing queries that involve rank computing PostgreSQL full-text search

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, full-text-search

Suppose we have a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` that has to be searched using PostgreSQL full text search. View contains both fields with information about the object and precompiled (and annotated with weigths) `ts_vector` fields for search and ranking. Also the `btree_gin` index is present.

When testing search time, it becomes clear that most of the search time is spent on rank computation. For instance, consider two quries.

First query (with rank).

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT
        -- i skipped here selecting other data that is unrelated to search
       "search_view"."profile_search_vec",
       "search_view"."nickname_search_vec",
       "search_view"."bio_search_vec",
       "search_view"."hashtags_search_vec",
       "search_view"."posts_text_search_vec",
       ts_rank('{0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05}', ("search_view"."profile_search_vec" || "search_view"."nickname_search_vec" || "search_view"."posts_text_search_vec" || "search_view"."bio_search_vec"), plainto_tsquery('makeup | beauty'))
           AS "rank"
FROM "search_view"
WHERE (search_view.profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup')) OR (
          search_view.profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty')
    );
```

```
Gather  (cost=2499.91..1617589.16 rows=109238 width=641) (actual time=89.861..7803.183 rows=54027 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=52118 read=38968
  I/O Timings: read=20336.075
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on search_view  (cost=1499.91..1605665.36 rows=45516 width=641) (actual time=67.236..7732.196 rows=18009 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: ((profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)))
        Heap Blocks: exact=7734
        Buffers: shared hit=52118 read=38968
        I/O Timings: read=20336.075
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=1499.91..1499.91 rows=111508 width=0) (actual time=68.831..68.837 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=20 read=51
              I/O Timings: read=41.590
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..28.02 rows=502 width=0) (actual time=12.068..12.068 rows=780 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2
                    I/O Timings: read=3.962
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..31.78 rows=1005 width=0) (actual time=3.475..3.475 rows=1526 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
                    I/O Timings: read=1.135
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..137.12 rows=12916 width=0) (actual time=13.655..13.655 rows=12763 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=7
                    I/O Timings: read=9.333
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..295.36 rows=30281 width=0) (actual time=12.390..12.390 rows=29181 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=8
                    I/O Timings: read=7.399
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..327.34 rows=34012 width=0) (actual time=8.676..8.676 rows=32472 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=9
                    I/O Timings: read=5.193
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..26.94 rows=359 width=0) (actual time=2.861..2.861 rows=717 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2
                    I/O Timings: read=2.695
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..39.86 rows=2081 width=0) (actual time=3.424..3.424 rows=2516 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
                    I/O Timings: read=3.006
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..112.13 rows=10118 width=0) (actual time=4.748..4.748 rows=9925 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6
                    I/O Timings: read=3.310
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..102.44 rows=8826 width=0) (actual time=2.712..2.713 rows=7555 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=5
                    I/O Timings: read=1.886
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..125.82 rows=11409 width=0) (actual time=4.814..4.815 rows=10002 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6
                    I/O Timings: read=3.670
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=10
Planning Time: 6.553 ms
Execution Time: 7810.917 ms
```

Second query (without rank computation)

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT
        -- i skipped here selecting other data that is unrelated to search
       "search_view"."profile_search_vec",
       "search_view"."nickname_search_vec",
       "search_view"."bio_search_vec",
       "search_view"."hashtags_search_vec",
       "search_view"."posts_text_search_vec"
FROM "search_view"
WHERE (search_view.profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup') OR
      search_view.posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup')) OR (
          search_view.profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty') OR
      search_view.posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty')
    );
```

```
Gather  (cost=2499.91..1605755.00 rows=109238 width=637) (actual time=49.096..331.439 rows=54027 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=19971 read=3296
  I/O Timings: read=603.846
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on search_view  (cost=1499.91..1593831.20 rows=45516 width=637) (actual time=44.546..282.632 rows=18009 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: ((profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text)) OR (profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)) OR (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text)))
        Heap Blocks: exact=12161
        Buffers: shared hit=19971 read=3296
        I/O Timings: read=603.846
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=1499.91..1499.91 rows=111508 width=0) (actual time=44.177..44.184 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=20 read=51
              I/O Timings: read=24.863
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..28.02 rows=502 width=0) (actual time=2.055..2.055 rows=780 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2
                    I/O Timings: read=1.491
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..31.78 rows=1005 width=0) (actual time=3.277..3.278 rows=1526 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
                    I/O Timings: read=2.645
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..137.12 rows=12916 width=0) (actual time=4.827..4.828 rows=12763 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=7
                    I/O Timings: read=2.249
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..295.36 rows=30281 width=0) (actual time=15.713..15.713 rows=29181 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=8
                    I/O Timings: read=10.001
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..327.34 rows=34012 width=0) (actual time=5.339..5.339 rows=32472 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('makeup'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=9
                    I/O Timings: read=2.040
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..26.94 rows=359 width=0) (actual time=0.503..0.503 rows=717 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (profile_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2
                    I/O Timings: read=0.359
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..39.86 rows=2081 width=0) (actual time=1.275..1.275 rows=2516 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (nickname_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
                    I/O Timings: read=0.862
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..112.13 rows=10118 width=0) (actual time=5.124..5.124 rows=9925 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (bio_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6
                    I/O Timings: read=1.361
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..102.44 rows=8826 width=0) (actual time=1.867..1.867 rows=7555 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (hashtags_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=5
                    I/O Timings: read=1.005
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin_btree_fulltext_search_idx  (cost=0.00..125.82 rows=11409 width=0) (actual time=4.190..4.190 rows=10002 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (posts_text_search_vec @@ to_tsquery('beauty'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6
                    I/O Timings: read=2.849
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=10
Planning Time: 1.010 ms
Execution Time: 335.726 ms
```

As you can see the second query runs a lot faster. I understand that one of the slowing factors can be I/O operations from disk (when shared buffers are not being hit.)

Is there any ways to optimize the first query to compute `rank` faster? Can `RUM` index help here in some way?

PS: I know the `WHERE` clause looks weird and can be rewritten, it looks like that because  these queries are actually generated by the ORM.

Comment: " I understand that one of the slowing factors can be I/O operations from disk (when shared buffers are not being hit.)"  You are aware of it, but what have you done to control for it?  It appears to me that this is the dominant factor, not the rank computation.

Comment: "Also the btree_gin index is present" How is btree_gin relevant to this?  I think you have some terminology confusion.